# Youtube embed html for uiwebview not working (on iOS 4.2 iPhone 3G)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, youtube

I have a UIWebView with the following embed code in it:

```
<embed id="yt" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1T6YM7RE5wQ" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="280" height="186"></embed>
```

This works fine on my iPhone 4 (iOS 4.3) but when testing on an iPhone 3G (iOS 4.2), the fullscreen youtube player appears, but stalls/hangs on "Loading Movie..."

Should I be using a different embed code for 4.2?  Should I be using a different embed code altogether?

Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks guys.

dunc

Comment: I am also having this problem on an iPhone 3G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<iframe id="yt" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="280" height="186" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/1T6YM7RE5wQ" frameborder="0">
```

It's using the HTML5-video element instead of referring to the flash.

Comment: I'm not working on this project now, but if someone else can confirm this works, I'll mark it as the answer.  Thanks Jensen2k.

Comment: Oh, gosh. Did not see that it was an old post. Sorry. But, it should by all means work. Mobile Safari uses WebKit, and WebKit supports HTML5-video like a charm.

Comment: OK mate.  I'll try it out a some point and get back to you. Thanks for your support anyway!